# Geotiff image overlay mismatch with Folium map

Tags: python, overlay, raster, folium, geotiff

I try to overlay a Gtiff image ([data.tif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14KisoC0QRp2LqUbBC1gVuncGyRMe9OBM/view?usp=drive_link)) on a Map using Folium. The result is almost correct but there is a slight offset in the inner pixels (see [Folium map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAc4o.png)).

When I display the Gtiff image in QGIS the result is fine (see [QGIS map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ETnr.png)). When I display the result using the georaster-layer-for-leaflet directly (without using folium) the result is also fine so I guess the problem comes from the folium code. Changing the CRS to EPSG:4326 in Folium map or Mercator_project = True in folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay does not solve the problem

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
import folium
import branca.colormap as cm
from matplotlib import colors as colors

def mapvalue2color(value, cmap): 
    if (value == 0):
        return (1, 0, 0, 0)
    else:
        return colors.to_rgba(cmap(value), 0.7)   #alpha channel=0.7 tuple (r, g, b, a)
colormap = cm.LinearColormap(["red", "magenta"], vmin = 6, vmax = 8) 

folium_map = folium.Map(location=[46.3, 3.5], tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=10, max_zoom = 18, crs="EPSG3857")#3857 "EPSG4326" 

ds = gdal.Open("./data.tif")
img = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
GT = ds.GetGeoTransform()
xRes = ds.GetGeoTransform()[1]
yRes = ds.GetGeoTransform()[5]
width = ds.RasterXSize
height = ds.RasterYSize 
folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
    image = img,
    opacity = 0.5,
    bounds = [[GT[3]+height*yRes, GT[0]], [GT[3], GT[0]+width*xRes]],
    colormap= lambda value: mapvalue2color(value, colormap)
).add_to(folium_map)

lat = ds.GetGeoTransform()[3]
lon = ds.GetGeoTransform()[0]
 
folium.Marker(
    location=[lat+yRes*4,lon+xRes*9], #lat/long
    popup=folium.Popup("lat :"+str(lat+yRes*4)+ "<br>lon : "+str(lon+xRes*9), max_width = 500),
   ).add_to(folium_map)

map_path = "./map.html"
folium_map.save(map_path)
```